# How do I select git ignore Node.js AFTER I've already created a repository?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, ignore

I have made a new repository. It's a JavaScript/HTML/CSS project.

When I created the directory on my GitHub.com profile, I forgot to select git ignore Node.js from the git ignore dropdown menu.

Is there a way for me to ignore Node.js after I've already created the repository?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Change the .gitignore to add the Node.js and commit that file

Answer (score 18):

If `.gitignore` not already created just add a new file `.gitignore` with below content in your project directory. If the file already created you can add below content in existing file.

```
# Dependency directories
node_modules/

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# dotenv environment variables file
.env
```

You can find more suitable ignores here [Node.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore). After creating a new file run the following commands for update on upstream.

```
git rm -r --cached . 
git add .
git commit -m 'Removed all files that are in the .gitignore' 
git push origin master
```

This will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a new .gitignore file manually if it is not already created.
If a file is existing, you can edit .gitignore file and add  it into your repository.

Answer (score -2):

1. Create manually .gitignore file in root of repository.

   https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Node.gitignore
2. Copy the contents of the Node.gitignore file from the GitHub
   page. Paste the copied contents into your newly created ".gitignore"
   file.
3. Save the ".gitignore" file. By following these steps,
   you will have manually created a .gitignore file and added the
   recommended rules specific to Node.js projects from the provided
   link.

You may also add custom rules as per standard.

This file will help exclude unnecessary files and directories from version control, improving the cleanliness and organisation of your repository.